# Stationary if and only if Toeplitz matrix

Tags: stationarity, toeplitz

It is known that a stationary process (mean and autocovariance do not vary with respect to time and the 2nd moment is finite for all times) has a Toeplitz covariance matrix.

But is the converse true ? If a process has a Toeplitz covariance matrix, is it stationary ?

My guess is no, since we can just take a process $X_t=\mathcal N(t,\sigma^2)$ of independent realizations. Is this enough ?

So maybe a good characterization would be a constant mean process is stationary if and only if it has Toeplitz matrix, right ?

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of a stationary process, so please edit your question to state what you mean by a stationary process.